# Cleaning simple mandolin slicer with non removeable blade

Tags: equipment

I have a very simple mandolin slicer.  Blade is not removable.   Extremely hard to clean, even soaking, running through dishwasher on top rack. Can't even get a toothpick between blade and plastic frame.  Help.

Comment: What kind of grunge are you trying to remove from it? Have you tried a toothBRUSH, floss, a pot brush?

Comment: Can you show (link to) a picture of the mandolin ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to clean it is with timing. Use your spray nozzle as soon as you are finished using it so good doesn't have a chance to setup and glue to your mandolin.